# mysql php multilingual Arabic and hindi

Tags: php, mysql, multilingual, arabic

I have a field "scroller" with collation "utf8_unicode_ci" in mysql database.
I am trying to save an arabic text to this field.

When i insert it to the mysql directly it works.

Using this code below i tried to edit the field. When i echo it it displays correctly. But when it is saved using update its saving like "??????? : 89 ????? ?? ?????? AMRI ????????? ?????? ???? ??????? ????? ????? ???????" in the database.

```
echo "<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content=text/html; charset=UTF-8>";
require 'config.php';
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); 
mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8'); 
$scroller=htmlentities($_POST['scroller'],ENT_QUOTES,"UTF-8");
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
echo $scroller;
    $sql="UPDATE arab_scroller SET scroller='$scroller' WHERE page='$id1' ";
    if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
        {
            die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
        }
        header( 'Location:index.php' );
```

Please help me out

Comment: Have you confirmed that what you're posting is working right? Pasting arabic text into an iso8559 form is going to mangle it before it ever leaves the browser.

Answer (score 1):

I just tested same thing with Turkish. If your table's default collation is not UTF8, you might have these kind of problems.

Please try this first:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

And then try to run your code again.

Also, it is better to use `mysql_set_charset` instead of `SET NAMES`:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php

Answer (score 0):

You just change table Collation utf8_general_ci by default it takes latin;

OR

you run this query :

ALTER TABLE tbl_name DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;

This is really works with me.